Trouble installing driver for 0bda:c812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC
A week ago I successfully installed a driver for a usb wifi adapter (0bda:c812 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 802.11ac NIC). Then a couple days ago it stopped working, i.e. didn't even show up in ifconfig. After trying to install the driver again without remembering exactly which driver it was or what steps I had followed the first time, I finally looked in my browser history to find the somewhat obscure webpage I had followed the first time. I repeated the steps (for the rtw88 option) and it works again, shows up in ifconfig, etc. The driver name shown in usb-devices by the way is rtw_8822cu.
Question 1: why might the driver have stopped working? Is there any reason I should use a viable alternative driver, if one exists?
Before reinstalling rtw_8822cu, I tried following 3 or 4 other sets of instructions involving dkms, like here, here, and here. It seems like one of these approaches should have worked, but none did. Question 2: why didn't these work?
Anyway, I ended up with 2 other non-working drivers installed.
$sudo dkms status
ndiswrapper, 1.60: added
rtl8821CU, 5.4.1, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.13.1, 5.15.0-105-generic, x86_64: installed

Question 3: should I try to remove these and the subfolders created in the git clone process, or are they harmless?
Thanks! My system info from inxi -Fxz:
System:    Kernel: 5.15.0-105-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Gnome 3.38.4 Distro: Zorin OS 16.3 
       base: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Focal

